# Cordova Plugin to stop Video audio on lock screen

Tags: cordova, audio, video, cordova-plugins, lockscreen

I'm trying to get an app on the stores, right now android is throwing a fit because on lock screen the video keeps playing in the background.

I've found several fixes for native code but i am using cordova. The short term solution is to open it up in the youtube app or a new browser but I'd rather keep it all self contained.

Has anyone been rejected for this reason that was using cordova and what did you do to fix it?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: There are two event-handlers to help you out here: [resume](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.resume.html) and [pause](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.pause.html). From my experience the pause event is fired when pressing the home button or when the lock screen is being shown(assuming that you were in your app before). Resume is fired when waking your app up again by pressing the app icon or unlocking your phone(if you were in your app). You can use these events to stop(pause)/start(resume) your video/audio.